# RC-OTA versus gm-C integrator in CT Delta-Sigma

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, adc, active-filter, integrator

In the book "Understanding Delta-Sigma Converters" of S. Pavan, R. Schreier and G. Temes they are stating the following speed comparison of the RC-OTA and gm-C integrator:
*The impressive performance of an OTA-RC integrator is achieved by the negative feedback. By nature, this limits the bandwidth of operation to a fraction of the intrinsic speed of the OTA. The Gm-C integrator attempts to mitigate the speed issue by using an open-loop structure.*

Maybe I am missing something, but I would assume that using feedback would increase the bandwidth? The structures RC-OTA and GM-C integrators that I am talking about are depicted underneath:
[image]

Comment: Can you _edit your question_ to unwind those abbreviations, and possibly insert images of the two integrator configurations?

Comment: Added the corresponding architectures.

Comment: What makes think that feedback will increase the bandwidth? While there are other more technical reasons, I'd intuitively think that feedback will make the amplifier slower because of the non-zero loop delay happening when we feed back the output signal. On the other hand, a open-loop system just outputs anything is fed without any need of trying to supres an error signal, as all feedback systems do.

Comment: @ErnestoG: According to "Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits" of Razavi and [link](https://electronicspost.com/what-are-the-advantages-of-negative-feedback/), the gain decreases with 1+T, and the bandwidth increases with 1+T (T = loop gain). I understand your reasoning, but it clashes with what I have learned according to Razavi's book.

Comment: It is an integrator hence, your Ravazi argument is inapplicable. It's an integrator hence it's bandwidth is zero by definition.

Comment: @VegTo91 when you want a feedback amplifier, in order to make your gain predictable, you need a large open-loop gain, probably >100dB at DC. Then, the closed-loop response will have an smaller gain but a larger -3dB bandwidth of the open loop gain (which is obviously very small because the dominant pole is usually at 1-10Hz). That's what he's referring to.

Comment: That being said, to be honest, I don't even agree with the statement of Shanti Pavan, because these trasnconductors need "source degeneration" (which is not other than series-series feedback) to have a predictable Gm, that is just fundamental. So, I'd change his statement to "trasnconductors are faster than voltage amplifiers for our performance requirements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the use of "open-loop" by Pavan in *"The Gm-C integrator attempts to mitigate the speed issue by using an open-loop structure."* (As per the OP's question), is not precise. Let's just look at the next paragraph in his book:

> Unfortunately, the Gm-C structure is problematic on several fronts. There are many,
> many ways of implementing a transconductor. Those that use open-loop techniques have
> limited linearity, which is strongly dependent on device characteristics. Others use feed-
> back to linearize the transconductor, which reduces speed of operation. Further, the inte-
> grator is sensitive to parasitic capacitances. Gm-C integrators are useful only when speed
> is the primary consideration, with linearity being less important.

There are transconductors that are truly open-loop, I believe the PhD thesis of Prof. Boris Murmann uses them to gain some power efficiency in his ADC design while doing all the corrections in the digital domain. On the other hand, many transconductors in the literature do use the so-called "source degeneration", which is another name used for plain series-series feedback (which happens to be the kind of feedback you should use if you want to fix the transconductance transfer of your amplifier), so there's nothing that is "open-loop" about them.

So, not all Gm-C filters are implemented in an open-loop way. It seems to me Pavan is sort of contradicting himself in this second paragraph.

That being said, I can believe that a transconductance amplifier transfer can be faster than that of a voltage amplifier, since little voltage swing should be expected at the output of the transconductor assuming it is connected to a low-impedance node. Low swing means parasitic capacitors don't take time charging up to high voltages... that I can believe.

Therefore, I think his conclusion is correct, but the way he argumented it isn't precise.

Comment: The closed-loop gain and BW are respectively lower and higher than in the case of an open-loop system (just like you were saying and what Razavi was stating). Still, this still leads to a contradiction with Pavan his statement that using feedback for linearization reduces the speed of operation. The only thing that I would think is, that adding feedback can underdamp or overdamp your system's output, which will deteriorate your speed.

Comment: @VegTo91 the problem is that saying that your amplifier is faster because you have used feedback and your "bandwidth has been extended" isn't accurate either. The initial bandwidth was only valid for a very high gain, while the larger bandwidth is valid for an smaller gain. No one uses an op-amp with high gain as an open loop amplifier, so it is meaningless to say that using feedback speeds up your amplifier.

Comment: @VegTo91 Pavan's statement about feedback reducing speed, as I said in my answer, is inaccurate at best. You have to understand that he's most likely comparing an open-loop amplifier that has been sized to produce a certain gain (at least for a small-signal) while the closed-loop amplifier has the same gain, but internally has a huge open-loop gain. It's in that situation only, IMHO, that saying that adding feedback will slow down the response of the amplifier. I can imagine that the open-loop amplifier will have a larger bandwidth than the closed-loop one, all else being equal.

Comment: @VegTo91 now, these open-loop amplifiers have a very small gain. I cannot imagine them having more than 10dB of gain without going into trouble.

Comment: Ok, in that kind of sense. Depends how you interpret it... Thanks.

Comment: @VegTo91 thanks for the vote. If you want to chat, I'm open to it. I've encountered more cases where students get confused by some of the statements in these standard books. I'd also trip if I were a beginner, but after 5+ years of IC design, one gets the hang of it :)

Comment: Not only students ;-)

Comment: You could also see it as the following:

OTA-RC: in this configuration, the gm should be very large. Mostly, not a simple structure (e.g. multiple stages, i.e. slow) in order to achieve a virtual ground at the inverting input

Gm-C: should not have a very large amplification. Thus, mostly simple structure is OK (i.e. fast), besides having the linearization techniques as degeneration resistors.

Comment: @VegTo91sounds like it. Though I'm not sure what's the difference between a Gm and a OTA... sounds like they should both provide a good transconductance transfer.

Comment: Well, in the design of an open-loop continuous time integrator, the gm should not be necessarily very large, compared to an OTA-RC. This is because the transfer function is gm/sC, whereas for an OTA-RC the transfer function is 1/sRC (if the OTA has infinite gm).

Comment: @VegTo91 gm/sC and 1/sRC are exactly the same transfer. I understand both of them have to be designed differently, but sometimes I find these arbitrary names in the literature annoying.